# ActionBarSherlock getMenuInflater issues

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have recently taken the ABS4.0 dive.  However, I appear to be having an issue using the MenuInflater.

When using the getMenuInflater() method, I receive an error message stating: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.view.MenuInflater to com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater"

So, it looks like the definition is picking up the ABS version of menu inflater but the getMenuInflater() method is returning the base Android version.  Code below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Try changing `getMenuInflater()` to **`getSupportMenuInflater()`**

Comment: If this is within a `Fragment` you will need to call `getSherlockActivity().getSuportMenuInflater()` or cast it appropriately via `getActivity()` ie...`(SherlockActivity)getActivity()...`